# GCM Result Analysis

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification using GCM. Everything works fine. But sometimes my user uninstall apps and after I tried to send push notification I am getting **Failed ERROR**

For example I have sent push notification to 200. Out of them 
25 failed
3 canonical and remaining success.

I want to remove ID From my DB whose request is failed. But I am unable to map with my db. How to Resolve this issue ?

One more point if I keep all failed id as it is and sending continuous push then google will take any actions or block my account or not ?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

`{"multicast_id":8019827747662309947,"success":203,"failure":110,"canonical_ids":5,"results":
[
{"registration_id":"APA91bE6fQmRZYCali6WQVkNdMpjo0RG0p4J6YfAEmrqAnRHbMTunEfUBB8DiJ3TwC6IEvTFVRKwzTc6ugnrYaFcPaxfxiLXiUDDh0pCdDxbyKTRwaLS167Po_FYKvcYEmWkiMc-HimweQ557SrGFiAKDMbhcEgWFu9beNkOAqHwmlBccbXJsaw","message_id":"0:1417935604786234%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},
{"error":"NotRegistered"},
{"registration_id":"APA91bEZgM7DZd_78gE4HbrDa2fvcN7F2yH-p4iDQbzryqkMu7k-DsvgluZh06H_rlpczAV0wta0fUofqS2p4HJHvn-vMn8X4FFA633K-AnIwIQcX52u6nCBVlTK5tSoFyKAoyw0_JepbLO5Yi4tg35vGk5eSaH14Q","message_id":"0:1417935604785344%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793003%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604787950%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604792619%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784886%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784870%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604783830%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604782887%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793008%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794867%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604783802%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604783800%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784663%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604785422%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604783959%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604786992%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784882%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784866%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784884%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784868%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784880%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604783961%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794871%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604785485%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604784888%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604786979%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604786985%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794962%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604787954%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604783828%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604797999%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798123%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604787945%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789960%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604785483%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604787952%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604788700%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604788969%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604786983%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796876%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604786989%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798913%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604787948%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604788971%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604790954%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604797737%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604790746%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"registration_id":"APA91bEZgM7DZd_78gE4HbrDa2fvcN7F2yH-p4iDQbzryqkMu7k-DsvgluZh06H_rlpczAV0wta0fUofqS2p4HJHvn-vMn8X4FFA633K-AnIwIQcX52u6nCBVlTK5tSoFyKAoyw0_JepbLO5Yi4tg35vGk5eSaH14Q","message_id":"0:1417935604786987%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"registration_id":"APA91bEZgM7DZd_78gE4HbrDa2fvcN7F2yH-p4iDQbzryqkMu7k-DsvgluZh06H_rlpczAV0wta0fUofqS2p4HJHvn-vMn8X4FFA633K-AnIwIQcX52u6nCBVlTK5tSoFyKAoyw0_JepbLO5Yi4tg35vGk5eSaH14Q","message_id":"0:1417935604786981%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"registration_id":"APA91bEZgM7DZd_78gE4HbrDa2fvcN7F2yH-p4iDQbzryqkMu7k-DsvgluZh06H_rlpczAV0wta0fUofqS2p4HJHvn-vMn8X4FFA633K-AnIwIQcX52u6nCBVlTK5tSoFyKAoyw0_JepbLO5Yi4tg35vGk5eSaH14Q","message_id":"0:1417935604786977%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604788698%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604788531%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604786991%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604790960%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604788300%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604792996%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604800742%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798919%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789897%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799772%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798917%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604792997%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794964%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796192%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604795473%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793000%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789895%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604790956%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789507%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789893%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789899%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789901%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789958%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604791828%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798911%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793002%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794647%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604792994%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789751%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604789962%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793010%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793006%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604791826%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604790962%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794875%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604790958%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793930%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793961%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604791517%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793963%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798902%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793943%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799897%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604797991%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604797997%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798001%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802426%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604792574%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604795765%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796916%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796803%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799943%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793958%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793932%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793941%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796914%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604793965%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794869%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798904%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798003%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796784%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802990%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798017%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794873%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796801%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794960%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796878%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604797993%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794649%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604803948%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796765%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796796%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796799%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794983%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798009%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796761%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604797986%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799771%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604795445%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798007%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604796805%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604795985%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798739%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604794966%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604795980%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604795982%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798011%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798005%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799937%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604797989%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799892%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604797995%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604795984%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799901%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604804602%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798921%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604805966%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604800946%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798915%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802008%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798725%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798015%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604798013%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799888%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799769%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799890%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604800875%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799941%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799899%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604800877%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604801966%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604805961%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799938%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604808935%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604800743%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604799583%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604809415%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802012%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802423%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604805964%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604809528%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802002%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802984%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802986%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604800881%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604801964%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604801974%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604801968%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604810609%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604800948%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604801822%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604800879%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604801970%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604801976%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802006%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802000%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604801972%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802004%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802980%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802285%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802425%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802009%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604803705%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604808933%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604803946%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604802988%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604803230%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604805960%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604804532%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604808794%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604806484%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1417935604803944%0ba8b24cf9fd7ecd"}
]
}`

Comment: shall i suggest you another easy way to send push notifications ?it is much easier to implement.

Comment: yes sure.. i will tryout another way also.

Comment: try parse.com, there is a 16 min youtube tutorial follow only that, and make an account in parse.com, here is the working project but you need to get keys from your parse account https://github.com/FoamyGuy/ParseNotificationExample

Answer (score 1):

The mapping of errors to registration IDs is based on the order. If your request has Registration IDs 10 20 30 40, and the response from Google shows errors for the 2nd and 4th IDs, you know that these errors refer to the 2nd and 4th IDs in the array of Registration IDs you sent (i.e. 20 and 40).

As the example from the GCM docs shows, if this is your request :

```
{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

and this is your response :

```
{ "multicast_id": 216,
  "success": 3,
  "failure": 3,
  "canonical_ids": 1,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:0408" },
    { "error": "Unavailable" },
    { "error": "InvalidRegistration" },
    { "message_id": "1:1516" },
    { "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" },
    { "error": "NotRegistered"}
  ]
}
```

you know that the 2nd (8), 3rd (15) and 6th (42) IDs failed and the 5th ID (23) returned a canonical Registration ID.

As to whether there are any sanctions when sending messages with the same bad Registration IDs multiple times - there is no documentation of that in the GCM docs, but I think it's in your own best interest to keep your DB clean of garbage. It would save your server some useless work (sending messages to invalid IDs), keep your DB smaller (even if it's only a small difference), and give you a good estimate of the number of users who use your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But Sometimes I am unable to locate due to canonical id is in between. Is there any other function where we can pass id and check out that its live or not ?

Comment: @Asp Canonical IDs in between should cause you any problem. See my edited answer for an example. All that is required of you is to know which IDs you sent to GCM in your last request and the order in which they were sent.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, I have edited my questions with my actual response from gcm. Kindly review it and let me know how to track ?

Comment: @Asp You should put the response you got from Google in an array. Each element of the array would be some class that contains message ID, error code and canonical registration ID. Then, for each index of the array that contains an error code, find the registration ID of the same index in the array of registration IDs you sent to GCM. Do the same for the indices that contain canonical registration IDs to find the old registration ID that maps to the canonical one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Let me tryout and will post reply shortly.